# Cucumber: all scenario's "when" in one go

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

Is it possible to run all scenarios "when" in only one go?

I'm currently working on a project where I need to migrate one database to another database and I want to use Cucumber to do an EndToEnd test. So each test fills the first database, then the migration is done and finally, I would test the second database. However, as the migration is pretty long I would like to do all the database filling first, then start 1 migration, and finally do all the tests.

I know it would not be good practice as the tests would not be isolated but I don't really have a choice. The only solution I can think of currently would be to make only one scenario but it would make it way too big.